# ASP.NET MVC website NOT in virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have deployed three mvc pages to my server as virtual directories using IIS (which there are plenty of tutorials for). I need one of the apps to run when the base URL is requested. So, for example, I have a Help app which can currently be accessed via help.contoso.com/help but I want that app to run when a user simply goes to help.contoso.com instead. I gather there is some sort of redirect option but can't find an example for this type of request anywhere (they're all way more complicated and don't address my simple need). I also think there should be a way to just host the app as the 'root' web 'page' but can't find anything around that either...